# Read data from text file into dictionary

Tags: python, csv, dictionary

using python, I am importing data from a text file with below sample data:

```
ABB : {'Code': 'adr', 'Volume': 2238117, 'Sector': 'Industrials', 'Market_Cap': 'No Data', 'Industry': 'Industrial Products', 'List_Date': '2001-04-06'},
ABEV : {'Code': 'adr', 'Volume': 19348239, 'Sector': 'Consumer Defensive', 'Market_Cap': 'No Data', 'Industry': 'Beverages - Alcoholic', 'List_Date': '2013-11-11'},
```

I am importing it into a dictionary with the following snippet:

```
with open('list_all.csv', mode='r') as infile:
    reader = csv.reader(infile)
    result = {}
    for row in reader:
        key = row[0]
        result[key] = row[1:]
```

it does get imported as a dictionary but the issue is because the KEY is not in "" such as `"ABB"` or `"ABEV"` . once I import it my dic looks like:

```
"ABB : {'Code': 'adr'": [" 'Volume': 2238117",
  " 'Sector': 'Industrials'",
  " 'Market_Cap': 'No Data'",
  " 'Industry': 'Industrial Products'",
  " 'List_Date': '2001-04-06'}",
  ''],
```

what is the best way to try to resolve this problem

Comment: Is that the actual contents of your "csv" file? It looks like you should be reading it line by line, splitting on ` : ` and then apply `ast.literal_eval` to what looks like the `dict` part?

Comment: yes, the first snippet is two actual lines from the CSV file. separated by comma at the end there. `KEY : {dic},`

Comment: That's not a CSV file to begin with, it appears as a list of _named_ dictionaries.

Comment: yes you are correct in that regard @zwer .  maybe would be easier to save as txt file and bring it in that way.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By the looks of it, you can read line-by-line, remove any trailing commas and split on the `:` and `ast.literal_eval` the `dict` part, eg:

```
import ast

with open('yourfile') as fin:
    rows = (line.rstrip('\n,').partition(' : ') for line in fin)
    data = {r[0]: ast.literal_eval(r[2]) for r in rows}
```

Which give you `data` of:

```
{'ABB': {'Code': 'adr',
  'Volume': 2238117,
  'Sector': 'Industrials',
  'Market_Cap': 'No Data',
  'Industry': 'Industrial Products',
  'List_Date': '2001-04-06'},
 'ABEV': {'Code': 'adr',
  'Volume': 19348239,
  'Sector': 'Consumer Defensive',
  'Market_Cap': 'No Data',
  'Industry': 'Beverages - Alcoholic',
  'List_Date': '2013-11-11'}}
```

Comment: thank you , this worked perfect. I did not know anything about `ast`  this will come in handy for similar problems in the future.